# Access specific array() element

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach

My debug($planDetails) output is as below. Why can't I access the array elements in a standard way like:

```
    foreach ($planDetails as $planRow) :
        echo $planRow['Plan']['Applicant']['name'];
    endforeach;
```

I get **Undefined index:  Plan** error?

**I also tried:**  echo $planRow['Plan'][]['name'];

```
Array
(
[PlanDetail] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54
            [name] => BasicOne
        )


[Plan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 255
                    [monthly_cost] => 20.23
                    [age_id] => 14
                    [applicant_id] => 8
                    [plan_detail_id] => 54
                    [Age] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => 18-64
                        )

                    [Applicant] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [name] => Subscriber +2
                        )
               )
    [2] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 254
                   [monthly_cost] => 15.50
                   [age_id] => 14
                      [applicant_id] => 27
                [plan_detail_id] => 54
                   [Age] => Array
                       (
                           [id] => 14
                           [name] => 18-64
                       )

                   [Applicant] => Array
                       (
                           [id] => 27
                           [name] => Subscriber + 1
                       )

               )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($planDetails['Plan'] as $plan) {
    echo $plan['Applicant']['name'];
}
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks. I will accept your answer when the time limit is over (about 8 mins).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a level in the array. You want

```
$planRow['Plan'][0]['Applicant']['name'];
```